# Trouble deploying Django app to Heroku: name 'install' is not defined

Tags: python, django, heroku

EDIT: I narrowed down the problem to the presence of the "distribute==0.6.10" line in the requirements.txt file. Removing that line fixes the problem, and haven't run into any errors from that line not being there... yet.

I'm following the tutorial here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Everything was going well, until I got to the part titled "Running a Worker". I have the following in my requirements.txt file:

```
Django==1.3
amqplib==1.0.1
anyjson==0.3.1
celery==2.3.3
distribute==0.6.10
django-celery==2.3.3
django-kombu==0.9.4
django-picklefield==0.1.9
gunicorn==0.12.2
kombu==1.4.1
psycopg2==2.4.2
pyparsing==1.5.6
python-dateutil==1.5
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

And I added the appropriate celery config to the end of my Procfile and settings.py as indicated in the instructions. When I deploy the app I get the following error:

```
          Relaunching...
           Traceback (most recent call last):
             File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
           NameError: name 'install' is not defined
           Complete output from command /tmp/build_2o84wdweodb97/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/build_2o84wdweodb97/build/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-LIti3K-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /tmp/build_2o84wdweodb97/include/site/python2.7:
```

The full deploy log can be found here: http://pastie.org/2609107

Anybody seen this before or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a newer version of distribute fixed the problem.

```
distribute==0.6.21
```